# App crashes when file path is null

Tags: android

Hi when I do `File file = new File(tempPath)` app is crashing when `tempPath` is empty

```
File file = new File(tempPath);
if (!file.isFile());
```

Comment: What does the logcat say? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Check exists. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it accessing a invalid location on the hard memory of the device. If you are fortunate he will try to access `"/"`. To avoid this you should check if `tempPath` is empty this way:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tempPath)) {
}
```

`isEmpty` will return true both it the string is empty or null